# Rails - Find out where a url-helper points

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, url, routes

In rails, when I have a form with a path-helper, for instance `create_admin_shop_voucher_path` and I want to find out what controller action it points to, I look in routes.rb:

```
rake routes | grep 'create_admin_shop_voucher'
```

But how do I do the same for a url-helper, for instance `passed_url` ?

Comment: Wish I could help! I'd love to learn about this

Comment: Do you have any questions to my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets say you have this route in your `RAILS_ROOT/config/routes.rb` file

get "passed" => "passed#index", :as => :passed

If you call passed_url

rails will return the whole url. For instance `http://localhost:3000/passed`

if you call passed_path

rails will return the relative path `/passed`

*_url helper generates a URL that includes the protocol and host
name.  The *_path helper generates only the path portion.

So, the its the same route in your `RAILS_ROOT/config/routes.rb` file

In your case you can call `create_admin_shop_voucher_url` as well as `create_admin_shop_voucher_path`.

Mostly you should use the _path flavor. If you need to spec the host or
protocol (like for talking to another app or service), then use the _url
flavor.

I use _url when i want to pass for instance a subdomain to a link.